# Having trouble implementing multithread solution to run class method multiple times simultaneously?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to run this test() class method multiple times simultaneously with threading. While the code runs, the threads are running sequentially instead of simultaneously, and I can't figure out the reason why.
The threading logic that I'm using is this:

```
testing = Generator()
threads = []
for x in range(0,10):
    t = Thread(target=testing.test())
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

I have a suspicion it may be my **init**, but I'm not sure. If anyone could help me find a real solution so that I can run that method multiple times simultaneously, i'd be really grateful. My code is below.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import random
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process

itemlink = str(input("Please enter an item link: "))


def random_line(fname):
    lines = open(fname).read().splitlines()
    print('fuck you')
    return random.choice(lines)



class Generator(Thread):
    def __init__(self, itemlink):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.session = requests.Session()
        #self.proxy = random_line("proxies.txt")
        self.proxy = ''
        self.firstname = ''
        self.lastname = ''
        self.email = ''
        self.password = ''
        self.itemlink = itemlink
        self.partial_item_link = itemlink[20::]

    def test(self):
        self.proxy = random_line('proxies.txt')
        self.firstname = random.choice(["Jackson", "Aiden", "Sophia", "Emma", "Olivia", "Lucas", "Ava", "Liam", "Mia", "Noah", "Ethan", "Isabella", "Riley", "Caden", "Aria", "Mason", "Elijah", "Zoe", "Lily", "Michael", "Benjamin", "Emily", "James", "Chloe", "Abigail", "Avery", "Evelyn", "Daniel", "Jack", "Madison", "Caleb", "Alexander", "Daniel", "Jack", "Evelyn", "Isaac", "Cameron", "Julian", "Eli", "Peyton", "Mackenzie", "Maria", "Camilla", "John", "Lincoln", "Brayden", "Victoria"])
        self.lastname  = random.choice(["Smith", "Johnson", "Williams", "Jones", "Brown", "Davis", "Miller", "Wilson", "Moore", "Taylor", "Anderson", "Thomas", "Jackson", "White", "Harris", "Martin", "Thompson", "Garcia", "Martinez", "Lewis", "Hall", "Allen", "Young", "Hernandez", "King", "Wright", "Lopez", "Hill", "Scott", "Green", "Adams", "Baker", "Gonzales", "Nelson", "Carter", "Mitchell", "Perez", "Roberts", "Turner", "Phillips", "Campbell", "Parker", "Evans", "Stewart", "Sanchez", "Morris"])
        self.email = self.firstname + self.lastname + str(random.randint(00000,10000)) + '@gmail.com'
        self.password = 'k0rnsyrupWatchBot'
        #item_link = input("Please enter an item link")
        #print(self.proxy)
        # print(self.firstname)
        # print(self.lastname)
        #print('generating ebay account with ' + self.email)
        #print(self.password)

        self.proxy = {
            "http": self.proxy,
            "https": self.proxy
        }

        print('starting thread with {}'.format(self.email))

        #print(self.proxy)

        headers = {
            #headers that i'm passing
        }

        data = {

            #data that i'm passing
        }
        try:
            self.session.post('url', headers=headers, data=data, proxies=self.proxy)
            print('blah account with {} generated'.format(self.email))
        except:
            return


        # print(r.text)

        headers3 = {
            #more headers

        }


        s = self.session.get(self.itemlink, headers=headers3, proxies=self.proxy)
        page_soup = soup(s.text, 'html.parser')
        # print(page_soup)

        watch_link = page_soup.find('a', {'class': ' '})
        # print(watch_link)
        watch_link = watch_link['href']
        # print(watch_link)


        t = self.session.get(watch_link, headers=headers3, proxies=self.proxy)
        # s = sess.get(item_link, headers=headers3, proxies=proxy)
        # print(s.content)

        # print(t.text)
        if "ADDEDTO_ONE_LIST_MULTIPLE_OTHER" in t.text:
            print('item added to watch list')
        else:
            print('item not added to watch list')
            return

        return

    def view_bot(self):
        headers3 = {
            #more headers

        }

        self.session.get(self.itemlink, headers=headers3, proxies=self.proxy)


testing = Generator(itemlink)
threads = []
 for x in range(0,10):
     t = Thread(target=testing.test())
     threads.append(t)
     t.start()
 for t in threads:
     t.join()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
t = Thread(target=testing.test())
```

is *calling* `testing.test`! That results in each method call running sequentially within your setup loop before any of your threads even start. Instead you want to pass the function object itself, not it's result, to the thread.

Replace the above line with

```
t = Thread(target=testing.test)
```

Also, you wouldn't typically pass functions to manually created threads *and* inherit from `Thread`. Choose one or the other, in your case it'd be easiest to just not inherit from `Thread`.

Comment: hey, thanks for your response. the threads are starting all at the same time now but now this is happening:

`starting thread with JackBaker1952@gmail.com
starting thread with LiamMoore402@gmail.com
starting thread with NoahPhillips8677@gmail.com
ebay account with NoahPhillips8677@gmail.com generated
ebay account with NoahPhillips8677@gmail.com generated
ebay account with NoahPhillips8677@gmail.com generated
ebay account with NoahPhillips8677@gmail.com generated
ebay account with NoahPhillips8677@gmail.com generated
ebay account with NoahPhillips8677@gmail.com generated`

Comment: they're all starting threads with different emails but when it comes to the generation everything says that last email only